# zoom out particular element using fancyzoom

Tags: html, zooming

i am using fancyzoom to zoom out an image.
But on clicking particular element i wanted to zoom out div element with some id. Can i do it using fancyzoom?
I wanted the div element to be shown on clicking a div element.